# UML Do you still show composition/aggregate objects as member variables?

Tags: uml

If I had a class Airplane and a class Wing, if there was a composition relationship between the two, does Airplane have a member variable of type Wing in the class diagram, shown in the Airplane box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Compositions and aggregations are kinds of associations and are shown like associations, i.e., with lines between classes (with solid and hollow diamonds, respectively, on the containing side). As a general rule, if you have an attribute whose type is a class, your model is wrong.

Implementation is a completely separate matter from analysis/design. You may implement associations in a variety of ways, including using member variables e.g. in C++.

Answer (score 4):

ASCII art!

```
+-------------+ 1        1..* +----------+
|  Airplane   |<*>------------|   Wing   |
+-------------+               +----------+
```

where `<*>` represents a filled diamond, indicating composition.  I used multiplicity 1..*, since it's possible to have aircraft that are essentially a single wing (such as the B-2), and although nobody builds them anymore AFAIK, you have biplanes (2 or 3 wings, depending on how you're counting), triplanes, etc.

Comment: (+1) An ASCII art image worths 1 thousand words ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure at 100%, but as far I remember no. Is just implicit that u will'have a variable of type Wing.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't.  But that doesn't mean that you can't have an attribute that is of class type.   You just can't have both.  It's a choice about what you want to emphasise.